# EPL Errors with Nesper Patterns

Tags: esper, epl, complex-event-processing

I am experimenting with Nesper (.NET version of Esper) and ran into a few troubles that I just cannot understand. The following simple EPL (modeled after the tutorial) fails with an error:

```
select * from pattern [every (e1=SeenEvent -> e2=SeenEvent(ID=e1.ID)) 
where timer:within(1 min)]
```

The error I get is:

```
Property named 'ID' is not valid in any stream
```

My first suspect was the ID may not be exposed correctly in the SeenEvent class which derives from Observation class. But I confirmed that in Observation class property ID is defined as Public.

Is this a known issue with EPL? Is Nesper different from Esper (it's Java cousin)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try "select ID from SeenEvent" to confirm whether "ID" is actually exposed. The property names are case-sensitive, try "id" as well. Rename the property may also help.